# JQuery Toggle next div after click

Tags: jquery

I cant figure out to target the next div to show/hide it with JQuery.

JavaScript:

```
    $("a.more").live("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.show-more').toggle();
    });
```

DOM:

```
            <p>
                {{beschreibung}}
                (<a class="more" href="{{id}}"><i class="icon-plus"></i>)
            </p>

            <div class="show-more" style="display:none;">
                <p>
                   {{beschreibung_lang}}
               </p>
            </div>
```

Any ideas where the problem is?

**Failure between screen and keyboard: Missed the closing a TAG (-;**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element that is bound in the event handler is the anchor, and the anchor has no sibling elements, i.e. next() will not work. You need to first traverse up the DOM to the closest paragraph, and then find the next div etc.

`live()` is deprecated, and should be replaced with the delegated version of `on()` for dynamic elements, like so:

```
$(document).on("click", ".more", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('p').next('.show-more').toggle();
});
```

Comment: works so far but the div is not toggled. if i use $(".show-more").toggle(); it works but for all "show-more" on the page (;

Answer (score 3):

The click event is triggered on `a`, when you use `next` it'll search for `a` sibbling which class's `show-more`. To fix it use `parent` before `next`, so you'll search for a `show-more` which's after `p`.

`$(this).parent().next('.show-more').toggle();`

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```
 $("a.more").bind("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().next('.show-more').toggle();
});
```

Comment: You should use .on('click') instead of live('click') as .live() is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

The anchor tag and the div are not siblings so you have to up by using parent() -

```
   $("a.more").live("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().next('.show-more').toggle();
    });
```